# Armadillo compilation error with Eclipse CDT

Tags: c++, armadillo

I am compiling some application using Eclipse CDT, using OpenCV and Armadillo.
I get the following error,

```
In file included from /usr/include/armadillo:108:0,
             from /home/bmmo/workspace/GS/Source/IMU/MagRLS.h:11,
             from /home/bmmo/workspace/GS/Source/IMU/IMU_class.h:11,
             from ../Source/Navigation/NAV2/nav2_get_u.cpp:2:
/usr/include/armadillo_bits/lapack_bones.hpp:235:106: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before numeric constant
/usr/include/armadillo_bits/lapack_bones.hpp:236:106: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before numeric constant
/usr/include/armadillo_bits/lapack_bones.hpp:295:139: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before numeric constant
/usr/include/armadillo_bits/lapack_bones.hpp:296:139: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before numeric constant
In file included from /usr/include/armadillo:112:0,
             from /home/bmmo/workspace/GS/Source/IMU/MagRLS.h:11,
             from /home/bmmo/workspace/GS/Source/IMU/IMU_class.h:11,
             from ../Source/Navigation/NAV2/nav2_get_u.cpp:2:
/usr/include/armadillo_bits/lapack_wrapper.hpp:184:31: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before numeric constant
/usr/include/armadillo_bits/lapack_wrapper.hpp: In function ‘void arma::lapack::geev(char*, char*, arma::blas_int*, eT*, arma::blas_int*, eT*)’:
/usr/include/armadillo_bits/lapack_wrapper.hpp:195:74: error: ‘wi’ was not declared in this scope
/usr/include/armadillo_bits/lapack_wrapper.hpp:195:82: error: ‘vl’ was not declared in this scope
/usr/include/armadillo_bits/lapack_wrapper.hpp:195:86: error: ‘ldvl’ was not declared in this scope
/usr/include/armadillo_bits/lapack_wrapper.hpp:195:96: error: ‘vr’ was not declared in this scope
/usr/include/armadillo_bits/lapack_wrapper.hpp:195:100: error: ‘ldvr’ was not declared in this scope
/usr/include/armadillo_bits/lapack_wrapper.hpp:195:110: error: ‘work’ was not declared in this scope
/usr/include/armadillo_bits/lapack_wrapper.hpp:195:116: error: ‘lwork’ was not declared in this scope
/usr/include/armadillo_bits/lapack_wrapper.hpp:195:123: error: ‘info’ was not declared in this scope
```

I can compile a smaller application with no problem, but with a larger project (using the same configurations) I get this error. What could be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include the armadillo header before any OpenCV header.  I suspect OpenCV uses a few errant #defines which interfere with function and/or variable names used by Armadillo.